How to add reflections like glass on transparent image?
I imported some image (png which have already transparency aplied) in blender as a plane (a rectangle with 2 transparent stripes in the middle and 3 black stripes) in shading and other modes it displays to me so that the black stripes are reflected and those fields where it is transparent there is nothing. how to make those stripes both transparent and also have a reflective effect (like glass/shiny) just like those black stripes?
I tried to make this effect by mixing Principled BSDF and Transparent BSDF but this don't have effect - all image is glass or stripes are in other places. I want to make reflection material only on transparent area, or make it through all image without loosing a quality of black stripes.



Have you tried turning the Principled Roughness parameter to zero?

you should at least provide your shader node tree and tell us whether you are in material preview or in render preview.

@james_t The Roughness is used to determine how sharp the reflections are, it does not create reflections where the object is transparent (which is not just transmissive like glass, but invisible).

Why do you mix the Principled BSDF with a Transparent BSDF? The Transparent BSDF creates alpha transparency, which means the material is completely invisible where the Transparent BSDF is white. Glass is not invisible, it is transmissive. But even if you want it to be invisible there's no need for a Mix Shader - the Principled BSDF has an Alpha input for that. And if you actually want something like glass, then do not plug whatever is used as the mix factor into the Alpha input, but the (inverted) factor into the Transmission input of the Principled BSDF.

@GordonBrinkmann idk, just tried everything to make that to work.
You mean "Invert" option or other? This have 2 color links and 1 fac. I tried this also but no satisfaing results

@Chris added. I am in shading

PNGs cannot encode alpha. You’ll have to take that at face value and do your own research by reading some extremely well researched posts here. A reflection is RGB > 0.0, and alpha of 0.0. This becomes a pure add. The solution in Blender is sadly to only use EXRs, due to poor design.

With a combination of Transparent and Glossy shaders, weighted by a Layer weight or a Fresnel, you can achieve what I assume you're looking for


Curious: how would you then include the PNG image with Alpha?

Either with a second material, as I did for my image, or with an additional Mix shaders in the setup above, with a principled BSDF for the PNG and the alpha as the switching factor.

I fiddled around a bit, and despite the mess, it came out more or less what I wanted (that is, a glass/reflective effect over the whole object without losing quality and glare on the black stripes. The only thing that bothers me is that it's a bit messy on this one and that the glass effect is applied to the whole object (making the black stripes minimally faded by the glass effect), not just the transparent stripes between the black ones. So, as if there is a possibility, I would like to know how to apply the glass effect itself to these transparent (not black stripes).

I guess my previous comment regarding to materials or a mix shader answers exactly to these points. Otherwise, an example of what you want to active precisely would help.

After modifying to my needs I got something like this. And although it's a mess, I got what I wanted (a gloss/glass effect over the entire object, with as little as possible weakening/interference on black bars.
However, what I miss is the ability to completely isolate those transparent stripes from the object and only apply the glass effect to them, leaving the black stripes untouched.

